# Using mod-rewrite with multiple pages

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, subdomain, wildcard

**Simplified Question**

I changed `domain.com/folder/client.php?id=1` to `1.domain.com` with this .htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([^.]+).domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /client.php?id=%2 [QSA,NC]
```

Now I want to change `domain.com/folder/about.php?id=1` to `1.domain.com/about`.

Is it possible ? or is there any other ways to do this?

Thank you :D

---

**Old Question**

In my directory, I have 2 pages (`client.php`, `about.php`). I've already set a wildcard subdomain to the page directory and changed `domain.com/folder/client.php?id=1` to `1.domain.com`. This is my .htaccess code :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([^.]+).domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /client.php?id=%2 [QSA,NC]
```

Now, I need to add another page. So, in client.php page, there's a button to go to about.php page in the same directory. I tried 1.domain.com/about.php and it's not working.

Do I have to create another line of RewriteCond ? or is there any other ways to do this?

Thank you very much :D

---

Updated Code without working id

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$             [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([^.]+).domain.com$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/about                    [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /client.php?id=%2                   [QSA,NC]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$                [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/about                        [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !about\.php                    [NC]
RewriteRule . /about.php?id=%1                            [L,QSA]
```

**The code resolved the text in url box. Let's say `id=1`. Now it's showing 1.domain.com/about.

```
the php code : `$_GET["id"]` is not specified.**
```

Thanks to **faa** for the edit :D

---

**The Full Solution**

Refer [Using mod-Rewrite with 5 pages (wildcard sub-domain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871176/using-mod-rewrite-with-5-pages-wildcard-sub-domain)

Comment: Generally speaking, `about.php` or any file name is part of the URL-path, not of the host name. So, yes, you would need at least another condition directive to test and eventually capture that string. Can't say more because this: `in client.php page, there's a button to go to about.php page` doesn't help much to understand what you need. At least to me.

Comment: Now, from the main page, my link is `<a href="1.domain.com">` which means it will go to `domain.com/folder/client.php?id=1`. Now from the `1.domain.com` which means `domain.com/folder/client.php?id=1`, I want to go to `domain.com/folder/about.php?id=1`. In client.php page, how the button's that links to about.php `<a href` will be if I write another same condition ?

Comment: I've already edited the question to make it clearer. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

## This is the actual rule-set that works as it is according to the OP
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$             [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([^.]+).domain.com$   [NC]
# Added to exclude folder `/about`
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/about                    [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /client.php?id=%2                       [L,QSA,NC]

## This is the additional rule set
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$             [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/about                     [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !about\.php                 [NC]
RewriteRule . http://domain.com/folder/about.php?id=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Maps silently

`http://N.domain.com/about` with or without trailing slash

To:

`http://domain.com/folder/about.php?id=N`

For permanent and visible redirection, replace `[L,QSA]` with `[L,R=301,QSA]`

Comment: Yea thanks the code works but the id is not set. it also change to `http://domain.com/folder/about.php?id=`. What I expect is `http://N.domain.com/about` in the url box. it goes to the about page and it became like this `http://domain.com/folder/about.php?id=`. Thank you very much :D. and what if I got another page?

Comment: I thought it had finally worked. Ok, now the incoming and redirected URLs are like those in my answer and you say `"What I expect is http://N.domain.com/about in the url box. it goes to the about page and it became like this http://domain.com/folder/about.php?id="`. But that's exactly what it does the last rule-set in my answer, I think. What am I missing because can't get it?

Comment: Thank you for replying :D. Let's say the `id` is `1`. The current problem after using the written code is the `id` is empty. and it should be http://1.domain.com/about but it's showing `http://domain.com/folder/about.php?id=`. Again, the `?id=` is empty.

Comment: Okay. I understand. I can't see anything wrong and it works perfectly in several servers for me. But, let's see. Is the complete testing URL like this: `http://1.domain.com/about` or it has something else? Does the original rule pass the ID to `client.php`? I escaped some periods in my answer that were missing, you might try it again.

Comment: I've already edited the question. Now the `http://1.domain.com/about` works, thanks. But there's one problem, I've specified it in the new edited question. Thanks :D

Comment: **Does the original rule pass the ID to client.php?** yea. the original rule passes the id but the new rule is not passing it.. Thanks

Comment: Now try [R=301,L] instead of [L,QSA] so you can see the substitution URL. If you see the ID (1), the problem is with the PHP code in `about.php`. If you don't, let me know, please.

Comment: and if I add the id. it will catch the id

Comment: Yes, hardcoding the ID does it, but that's not what you need. Don't understand what's the problem, but will use the original rule that works for you. I will update my answer.

Comment: You are welcome. I updated my answer using exactly the same condition and back reference you have in the original rule. Note that I also removed the QSA flag. It should work

Comment: it's still not catching the id. I tried editing it too. But the result is still the same :(

Comment: And you don't see it. Right? If it works for `client.php` it has to work for `about.php`, there is no difference that affects the rule. The problem is the back reference (%2) is being passed empty to the substitution URL. I really don't understand why because it works in your original rule and in all the tests I made. Are you sure the browser's cache is cleared before any test?

Comment: yea. cleared the browser cache and still doesn't work. in client.php, the link to the about page is `<a href="http://<?php echo $id; ?>.domain.com/about"` and the $id variable has value. the original rule changes `http://domain.com/folder/client.php?id=1` to `1.domain.com`, NOT `1.domain.com/client`

Comment: I see. I will leave my rule as it was and suggest you test it entering directly in the browser's address bar `http://1.domain.com/about`. You can test it [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) if you want. I guess the problem is not with the mod_rewrite rules but at some point with the scripts. The test will help you to find out what's the problem.

Comment: it says all the rules met. Just these 2 lines not met  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/about                    [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /client.php?id=%2                       [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: but the id is specified in there

Comment: I triend entering it directly in url bar but it changes to `http://domain.com/folder/about.php?id=`

Comment: I guess it should be `http://1.domain.com/about`. Was the result in the test site positive, the resulting URL is the expected one?. If so, for some reason the scripts are not passing the ID.

Comment: Even if I type directly into the url box, `1.domain.com/about`, it's still not catching the id