# Using mod-Rewrite with 5 pages (wildcard sub-domain)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, wildcard

Let's say I got 5 pages (`index.php`, `about.php`, `portfolio.php`, `gallery.php`, `contact.php`).

Let's say the id is `1`.

The original url is :

`www.domain.com/folder/index.php?id=1`,
`www.domain.com/folder/about.php?id=1`
and so on...

Now, I want to change it to :

`1.domain.com/index`, 
`1.domain.com/about`, 
`1.domain.com/portfolio`, 
`1.domain.com/gallery`,
`1.domain.com/contact`

Is it possible with mod-rewrite ? And if I'm in the `index.php` page, whats the `<a href="" >` that goes to `about.php` if the mod-rewrite is possible?

Thank you very much :D I appreciate your help :D

**EDIT**

One more thing, My wildcard subdomain folder is `public_html/folder/`

**The Solution By [Anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)**

Edited with subdomain codes :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# EDIT BY ANUBHAVA: to make http://1.domain.com/ load /about as default page
# Replace /about with any other page you want as default page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1\.(domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /about [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([^.]+).domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index|about|portfolio|gallery|contact)/?$ /$1.php?id=%2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Make sure your wildcard subdomain directory is where the pages are. Also put your .htaccess file in the directory where the pages are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# EDIT: to make http://1.domain.com/ load /about
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1\.(domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /about [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1\.(domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index|about|portfolio|gallery|contact)/?$ http://www.%1/folder/$1.php?id=1 [R=302,L,NC,QSA]
```

Once that is in place create href links like this:

`<a href="http://1.domain.com/about">About Us</a>` or `<a href="http://1.domain.com/contact">Contact Us</a>`

Comment: What if the id change? Let's say it changes to `2`. And how to rewrite the subdomain `1.domain.com` ? Thanks for the answer :D

Comment: Oh didn't realize you wanted rewritten URL in `1.domain.com`, see the edited answer now. If your id changes then you just need to change above RewriteRule line.

Comment: It works but how to make `about.php` the default landing page if the user just enter `http://www.1.domain.com` in the browser url box ? Thank you very much, didn't know it will works with just 6 lines of codes :D. Thanks again. But can you help me with the default landing page :D

Comment: To make `/1.domain.com/about` as default page you can use my code from edit section above.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find which one is it. I'm still a newbie to mod-rewrite :D

Comment: To make my question clearer, when the user type `1.domain.com` in the url bar, it will show `Index of /` page with directory listings. How can I redirect it to `1.domain.com/about` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in the .htaccess file. write the below code in that it will hide the extension of the file.

```
   Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z])\$ $1.php [NC]
```

And after that you will give the URL in anchor link like /index and so on.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it now and how about the subdomain `1.domain.com`?